# Iso/iec 11801. What is a "Consolidation Point" enclosure?

Tags: iso, cable-management

I'm reading iso/iec 11801 standar, so i found that the consolidation point helps to the administration for relocating cables, I thought it would be a patch panel or something like this, but, the standar says that a Consolidation Point can't be used for cross-connect, what is this enclosure or how can I find it commercially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some education on the subject from an old article at http://www.ecmag.com/section/systems/allowing-modular-furniture-be-modular

It seems the basic idea is to put the consolidation point somewhere permanent, and run a "consolidation point cable" from there to a plate next to the user.  To your point about cross connections, "Interconnections, not cross-connections, shall be used at the consolidation point."

Web searches for "consolidation point cable" and "consolidation point enclosure" had some things for sale.

Comment: Well, thanks to the article now I understand that the Consolidation Point can be any connecting hardware. Now I think that I'm confusing about the concept of "Interconnection" and "cross-connection", at the beggining I thought it was related to color configuration for ethernet, for example a cable with both RJ45 configured by T568a (interconnect) and other with a RJ45 configured by T568a and the second by T568b. Now I'm doubting about that.